# Set multiple cells in the same column in CSV with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to have some values in the same column, currently my result displays that. The stats.csv is an Excel table.

The file "stats" after the export:

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  col1    col2    col3    col4
                ref     a       b       c       d
                ref     a2      b2      c2      d2
                ref     a3      b3      c3      d3
                ref     A       B       C       D
                ref     A2      B2      C2      D2
                ref     A3      B3      C3      D3
                ref     AA      BB      CC      DD
                ref     AA2     BB2     CC2     DD2
                ref     AA3     BB3     CC3     DD3
```

The current code:

```
$csv = Import-Csv .\ressources.csv -Delimiter ';'

$csv | Add-Member -Type Noteproperty -Name "Field1" -Value "prod"
$csv | Select-Object Field1,Field2,Field3,col1,col2,col3,col4 |
    Export-Csv -Path ".\stats.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" 

$csv = Import-Csv .\ressources.csv -Delimiter ';'

$csv | Add-Member -Type Noteproperty -Name "Field2" -Value "name"
$csv | Select-Object Field1,Field2,Field3,col1,col2,col3,col4 |
    Export-Csv -Path ".\stats.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"

$csv = Import-Csv .\ressources.csv -Delimiter ';'

$csv | Add-Member -Type Noteproperty -Name "Field3" -Value "ref"
$csv | Select-Object Field1,Field2,Field3,col1,col2,col3,col4 |
    Export-Csv -Path ".\stats.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

I would like to get this result (remove the `Field2` and `Field3` but keep the rows and include it):

```
Field1   col1  col2 col3 col4
prod     a     b    c    d
prod     a2    b2   c2   d2
prod     a3    b3   c3   d3
name     A     B    C    D
name     A2    B2   C2   D2
name     A3    B3   C3   D3
ref      AA    BB   CC   DD
ref      AA2   BB2  CC2  DD2
ref      AA3   BB3  CC3  DD3
```

The file "ressources" before importing:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
a     b    c    d
a2    b2   c2   d2
a3    b3   c3   d3
A     B    C    D
A2    B2   C2   D2
A3    B3   C3   D3
AA    BB   CC   DD
AA2   BB2  CC2  DD2
AA3   BB3  CC3  DD3
```

If you need more informations, I can edit to explain more.

Comment: You say you want to merge 3 fields, but the code you posted actually **creates** the three fields, so which of the two is it? And in case of the latter: where do the values for the additional fields come from (because they obviously aren't present in your in put file)?

Comment: My current code make the first output but i don't know how to make the expected output and for the edit I have to remove a part of the column at a certain name of row. I don't know how to generate only the rows. It is explained in the question, for each details.

Comment: It's clearly not possible that the code you posted would generate the first sample table from the third sample table.

Comment: I've edited, I think it's that you are talking about, I'm trying many things to get this possible and I forgot to take the right code.

Comment: The code you posted now would keep overwriting `stats.csv`, so you'd end up with just the last third of your alleged output. Please stop lying.

Comment: I've edited the file be patient please. I've forgot to edit, i'm lost in many files my desktop is full of excel table but this first file must be the good one.

Comment: *\*sigh\** Apparently you want to add **ONE COLUMN** (not three) with a different value **DEPENDING ON THE VALUES OF OTHER COLUMNS**. So would you please divulge the criteria by which you decide when `Field1` should get the value "prod", "name", or "ref"?

Comment: Like the example expected but it does not depends of the others columns, it's difficult to explain. My demand is in the question get one column, I know I did three columns because I actually don't know how to make it with one column. The rows of the Field1 column must change when I export for the seconde,third then fourth time. The best example that I can't show you is up there.

Comment: If you cannot define criteria when to add which value you cannot automate it. Period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) with a [`switch`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx) statement for adding a new field with a value depending on the value of some other column:

```
Import-Csv .\test2.csv -Delimiter ';' |
    Select-Object @{n='Field1';e={
        switch -regex -casesensitive ($_.col1) {
            '^[a-z]'      { 'prod'; break }
            '^[A-Z][A-Z]' { 'ref'; break }
            '^[A-Z]'      { 'name'; break }
        }
    }}, * |
    Export-Csv -Path '.\stats.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'
```

Obviously, you need to adjust the regular expressions to reflect your actual criteria.

Comment: Your answer is a specifical case if I include that in my current code this doesn't work, right ?

Comment: Just a question, How do you use the  `'^[a-z]'`(I mean you can use this many times in the same line) ? Is it possible with numbers ?

Comment: My answer uses the match criteria from your (now deleted) comment. Of course you need to adjust the expressions if your actual criteria are different.

Comment: What do you mean "how do you use"? Just like I showed in my answer. It matches a lowercase letter at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Can you tell me if it's possible with numbers and letters in with specials characters ?

Comment: The link you posted doesn't explain how to make that with something like k12e, if this case, I have this  `'^[0-99]' `and this `^[a-z]` ?

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Please find a tutorial on regular expressions if you're not familiar with them. That's beyond the scope my answer.